# Проблемы с работой GUI в Astra Linux

Tags: c++, qt, gui, astra-linux

Есть класс унаследованный от `QMainWindow`, в нем устанавливаю два `QDockWidget` и центральный виджет:

```
QWidget* centralWidget = new TreeWidget(this);
setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
QDockWidget* treeDockWidget = new QDockWidget( this );
treeDockWidget->setWidget( new TreeWidget );
treeDockWidget->setAllowedAreas( Qt::DockWidgetArea::AllDockWidgetAreas );
addDockWidget( Qt::DockWidgetArea::LeftDockWidgetArea, treeDockWidget );


QDockWidget* editorWidget = new QDockWidget( this );
editorWidget->setWidget( new EditorWidget( this ) );;
editorWidget->setAllowedAreas( Qt::DockWidgetArea::AllDockWidgetAreas );
addDockWidget( Qt::DockWidgetArea::LeftDockWidgetArea, editorWidget );
```

При растяжении любого виджета, он произвольно меняет свои размеры на размеры по умолчанию. Такое поведение проявляется только на Astra Linux. На Ubuntu 18.04 все работает правильно.

В чем может быть причина?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Он это что, - центральный виджет? Если так, то попробуйте изменить его `sizePolicy`

Comment: Обратитесь в техподдержку Астры

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось что это [ошибка в Qt](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-65592?focusedCommentId=412498&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel).